# How Do I Pivot An Array Of Objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object which I need to convert to a table (kind of pivoting the data). Saying this I need to get another array of objects with the unique titles which have nested arrays of object with pairs of the values. Could you please take a look into this and help with achiving what I need? Please see the original and the desired array below:

Original Array:

```
[
{title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
{title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
{title: "Title1", values: [{value1: "value1"}, {value2: "value2"}]},
{title: "Title2", values: [{value1: "value1"}, {value2: "value2"}]},
{title: "Title3", values: [{value1: "value1"}, {value2: "value2"}]},
]
```

Thanks if advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Too many duplicate "value1" "value2" for your example too make any sense.

Comment: is the outcome really the wanted outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a hash table for grouping as `thisArg` with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var data = [{ title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }, { title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2" }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {

    // check if title is not in hash table
    if (!this[a.title]) {

        // if not, create new object with title and values array
        // and assign it with the title as hash to the hash table
        this[a.title] = { title: a.title, values: [] };

        // add the new object to the result set, too
        grouped.push(this[a.title]);
    }

    // create a new object with the other values and push it
    // to the array of the object of the hash table
    this[a.title].values.push({ value1: a.value1, value2: a.value2 });
}, Object.create(null)); // Object.create creates an empty object without prototypes

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Nina! This is exactly what I wanted. May I ask you to add some comments to the code as I would love to get a better understanding of what we have here. However, it's not that Important, if you don't have time I will try to investigate everything by myself.

Answer (score 5):

A simple array reduce may be of help

```js
let data = [{
  title: "Title1",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title2",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title1",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title3",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title2",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title1",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title3",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}, {
  title: "Title1",
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}];

let pivoted = data.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  let existing = prev.find(x => x.title === cur.title);

  if (existing)
    existing.values.push(cur)
  else
    prev.push({
      title: cur.title,
      values: [cur]
    });

  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(pivoted);
```

**API's used**

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

This could then be adapted to pivot by any field you desire, it would need error handling adding if that field does not exist however:

```
let pivotBy = (key, data) => data.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  let existing = prev.find(x => x[key] === cur[key]);

  if (existing) {
    existing.values.push(cur);
  } else {
    let toInsert = {
        values: [cur]
    }

    toInsert[key] = cur[key];

    prev.push(toInsert);
  }

  return prev;
}, []);
```

**EDIT**
I misinterpreted your desired output format, however the reduce approach could be modified to fulfill that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var originalArray = [
      {title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title2", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title3", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
      {title: "Title1", value1: "value1", value2: "value2"},
    ];
    var newArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i<originalArray.length; i++){
      var object = {};
      object.title=originalArray[i].title;
      var values = [];
      values.push({value1: originalArray[i].value1});
      values.push({value2: originalArray[i].value2});
      object.values= values;
      newArray.push(object);
    }
```

This will work, although honestly, I don't know why you have some duplicated tittles. I supossed that it was just an example. If not, the answer is another.